# ASP.Net C# Use first Row from Reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

```
conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
comm = new SqlCommand("Products.sl_Cartridges", conn);
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrinterID", SqlDbType.Int));
comm.Parameters["@PrinterID"].Value = varPrinterID;conn.Open();

reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
Cartridges.DataSource = reader;
Cartridges.DataBind();
reader.Close();
```

Is there a way to add some code behind to the above to pick out the values of the first data row of this repeater? It would just save me writing a separate SP which seems a waste. Sorry very new to .Net!

Comment: Why does writing a separate SP seem like a waste?  It takes like 1 minute, it's a really good habit to be in, it's almost on extra effort to the server, and you can have less data being transferred over the wire.  I've done projects where we have 1000's of stored procedures to handle all the different amounts of data retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result set returned is very small, you can just dump to a DataTable with a SqlDataAdapter and grab the first row.  This is very simple but inefficient because it wastes a bunch of unnecessary data flow if the result size is large:

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

Cartridges.DataSource = new [] { dt.Rows[0] };
Cartridges.DataBind();
```

**Edit**: dt.Rows[0] is not valid because it must be a list.  Replace with `dt.Rows.Take(1)` (if you have LINQ) or `new [] { dt.Rows[0] }`.

Otherwise, you will need to grab all the values from the first row in the reader and dump them into an object that can be bound to the Cartridges control:

```
var firstRow = new { Name = reader[0], Value = reader[1], Blah = reader[2], ... };
Cartridges.DataSource = firstRow;
Cartridges.DataBind();
```

Also, if you use a control like DetailsView instead of Repeater, it will automatically display only one row at a time, and you can filter it to a single row.

Comment: Tried:

conn.Open();
reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
var firstRow = new { cartPicThumb = reader[2], cartPriceFrom = reader[5] };
Cartridges.DataSource = firstRow;
Cartridges.DataBind();
reader.Close();

Get error: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb: You might have to call `reader.Next()` once before you grab the first record.

Comment: sorry cant get it to work or using a SqlAdapter: An invalid data source is being used for Cartridges. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable.

Comment: Try `Cartridges.DataSource = new [] { dt.Rows[0] };`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very nice solution, but you could add a handler for the repeater's ItemDataBound event and set the Visible property of each item (except the first one) to false:

markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server"
  OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
```

code-behind:

```
private bool first = true;
void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!first) e.Item.Visible = false;
    first = false;
}
```